# How to isolate the log of a git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to show the git log of a submodule WITHOUT being inside it or interleaving?

Such as

```
git log <my_submodule>
```

And only see the commits to it from its remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to be inside a submodule, in order for `git log` to show all commits from the submodule repository.

You don't have to change folder yourself, though: the git command can do that for you.

```
git -C my_submodule log
```

(Assuming you are in the parent repository, and `my_submodule` is the root folder of the submodule, directly under the parent repository main folder)